# How to set initial sequence number of TCP socket

Tags: python, c, sockets, tcp

As a part of testing, I am needing to be able to initialize the ISN (initial sequence number) of a TCP connection to a specific value. Normally this is a randomized value picked by the OS/Network Stack, but I need to control the initial value.

Is there any way to do this in C or Python?

Comment: I'm fairly certain nothing standard exists for this. Which OS are you targeting ?

Comment: You will need to construct raw packets and send them. Here's [an example I found for Linux in Python](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-socket-programming-in-python-linux/).

Comment: @cnicutar I would be happy with either Linux or Windows as I have both of those available.

Comment: @netcoder I was really hoping to not have to deal with raw sockets as it seems like a lot more code to deal with. But maybe I can adapt the code in the link provided

Comment: @cottonke: I don't think it can be achieved otherwise. We're talking about changing the TCP header here, this is pretty low-level stuff. Besides, wrapping this in a function shouldn't be complicated at all.

Comment: You can run another IP stack like lwIP as an application, and hack it to do this.

Comment: @ErikEkman that seems very interesting ... but cannot come across any example to do this. Any pointers?

Comment: Out of curiosity - what do you want to test this way? Are you testing some TCP/IP stack?

Comment: @CodePainters Yes we are testing how different stacks react to these types of things. Doing evaluations to determine which we will go with.

Answer (score 0):

- Download [lwip](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/lwip.git) and [lwip-contrib](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/lwip/lwip-contrib.git).
- Create a new tap interface and bridge it with your normal network card
- Build the `lwip-contrib/ports/unix/proj/minimal` app and run it
- Now you should be able to ping the lwip stack
- TCP sequence number are in `struct tcp_pcb`, values `rcv_nxt` and `snd_nxt`
- Hack the TCP code to not randomize these values and add a TCP connection to the `minimal` app